# Can every recursive problem be solved by dynamic programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

I'm a newbie in DSA and I just realized that all of the DP problems have recursive solutions. By the way I was wondering if there can be always a dp solution for all of recursive problems? if so, then why don't we give up on divide and conquer and just use dp?

Comment: Isn't dynamic programming just an optimization over plain recursion that also uses divide and conquer? D&C is a broader principle than the narrow scope of recursion.

Comment: I think this paragraph from wikipedia answers your question rather well: [Wiki: Dynamic programming, optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming)

Comment: No. As a counterexample, what's the DP solution to binary search? DP is based on overlapping subproblems, and clearly there are tons of recursively-defined problems that have no overlap, like divide and conquer algorithms. Recursion is basically a fancy looping technique that isn't related to DP in any meaningful way. These 3 concepts are all distinct. What makes you think DP, recursion and D&C are interchangeable?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks a lot. that was really helpful.